# Jquery setInterval stops in separate tab

Tags: jquery, browser, tabs, setinterval, counting

I need my setInterval function to work even when the browser tab with current script is not active.
You can see my example here http://jsfiddle.net/4MWqV/.

```
var balance=100000000;
setInterval(function(){balance=balance+1;$('#balance').text(balance)},1);
```

When current tab is active the script runs fine, but when I switch to another window, the counting stops. 
How can I make this count work even in separate tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome

Comment: Base it off of the current browser time so that you don't care that it pauses when the tab changes.

Comment: @kevin-b can you explain the details?

Comment: the question that is marked as a duplicate does that pretty well.

Comment: @kevin-b I've tried and that didnt quite work with interval ov 1 millisecond as I need...

Comment: That's fine, but there's no way of making the interval continue when you change tabs. Checking on some other value, such as the current time, is going to be your only option.